# Rails select helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My setup: Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2

I have a global constant defined

```
TYPES = { "visa" => "Visa", "master" => "MasterCard" }
```

I wish to invert the values for the select method, I know it sounds silly but there is another part of my code that needs this functionality, so I'm trying to figure out if it is possible. Here's what I have so far but didn't work

```
<%= f.select :card_type, TYPES.each { |key, value| [value, key] } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `invert` method built-in to `Hash`:

```
TYPES = { "visa" => "Visa", "master" => "MasterCard" }

TYPES.invert
# => {"Visa"=>"visa", "MasterCard"=>"master"}
```

So:

```
<%= f.select :card_type, TYPES.invert %>
```

Notes:

1. Why not use symbols instead of strings for the key..  `:master` instead of `"master"`
2. The values of original `TYPES` will be used as the keys for the `invert`'ed `Hash`, so ensure that your values are all unique.

Comment: D'oh! How did I miss that? I even inferred it in my question LOL.